# Update GridView SelectCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView which initializes the page using the full contents of a table using source `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`

**testPage.aspx:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4] FROM [Analysis]
ORDER BY [Field1] DESC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

(I've changed the real field names!).

This works fine and the gridView populates with the full table data. Based on another event I now want to change the SelectCommand to filter the table using the SQL `WHERE` clause. I've tried

**testPage.aspx.cs:**

```
    protected void ctl04_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [Field1], [Field2], 
        [Field3], [Field4] FROM [Analysis] WHERE [Field1] = 'items' ORDER BY 
        [Field1] DESC";
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The event fires and appears to run fine but gridView1 doesn't refresh/update and still contains the data for the full table.

Can anyone give some pointers how to get this working?
Thanks

Comment: Try `GridView.DataSource = null;` before you reassign the select command.  This should force the `GridView` to rebind using the new `SelectCommand`.

Comment: That's not working for me, it runs okay but gridView1 still contains the full table data after the event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is `PostBack` and page load. When your page opened and Page_load method was called. then the `GridView` refreshed using default `SELECT` Statement. You should put refresh code into this code:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
{
   // Your Code
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's it. I've deleted the `ctl04_ValueChanged` event and  added `AutoPostBack="True"` then moved the code to the `Page_Load` event.

Answer (score 1):

how about Create 2nd sql data source and you can switch between them. I think that's happen because of post back